# JSON reading with NSURLSession broken result

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsurlsession, nsjsonserialization

As mentioned, I am reading JSON file from URL. If I access page, JSON format is valid and nice. In app, I am getting it with:

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
[[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlAsString]
        completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                            NSURLResponse *response,
                            NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"Error");
            } else {
                alreadyParsed = true;

                NSMutableDictionary* object = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
                NSMutableDictionary *posts = [object valueForKey:@"posts"];

                if (!object) {
                    NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON: %@", error);
                } else {
                    for (NSMutableDictionary *item in posts) {
                        NSLog(@"Item: %@", item);
                    }
                }

                NSLog(@"Data: %@", [object description]);
            }
        }] resume];
```

On page, JSON looks like:

```
    {
      "status": "ok",
      "count": 1,
      "count_total": 39,
      "pages": 39,
      "posts": [
        {
          "id": 948564,
          "title": "",
          "modified": "2016-02-17 21:32:26",
          "attachments": [],
"attachments_featured": [
        {}]
        },
        {
          "id": 948565,
          "title": "",
          "modified": "2016-02-17 21:32:26",
          "attachments": []
        }]
    }
```

but in app, I get:

```
2016-02-29 17:04:34.819 test[22835:1929421] Data: {
    count = 1;
    "count_total" = 39;
    pages = 39;
    posts =     (
                {
            attachments =             (
            );
.
.
.
```

Between posts array and attachments there should be more data but I cannot figure out what is going on and why it is not displayed.

I tried getting page data into string and printing it and it shows fine. Also tried that string converting into NSData and creating out JSON, but result is the same. Anyone has any idea what is going on?

Comment: Objects are not ordered so the data might just as well come after "attachments" when you run your code. What do you get where you just typed ". . ." ?

Comment: @Stefan You are right, data is not ordered and is below attachments. I am parsing later in code this data and it was working before. Nothing has changed in code nor on the server side and suddenly it stopped working.
The thing that is bothering me is that in app's output there is no [ brackets and there are ; chars, which JSON doesn't have. Is this some kind debugger output thing?

Comment: `NSLog()` uses the `description` method and the format that is output is just what the Apple developer who wrote the `description` liked. Some strings are not quoted and some are, this has been resolved in Swift. The `description` does not even try to produce JSON, `NSData` pre-dates JSON.

Comment: I noticed that there is some data missing, for example "attachments_featured" is empty in my app. And that is the main part of my data. This is weird since I am not doing anything to the result.